# Drivers for Logitech Formula Force Wheel on WIN XP Professional

Tags: windows-xp, game-controller, logitech-gamepad

I need drivers for Logitech Formula Force Wheel and Pedeals with a serial connection, for use on Windows XP Professional.  XP Professional is version 2002.

Answer (score 2):

This download should sort out your problem:

[Logitech Formula Force GP 4.60 Driver for Windows XP Free Download - Softpedia](http://drivers.softpedia.com/progDownload/Logitech-Formula-Force-GP-460-Download-15083.html)